# Getting Error while executing the python script in readyAPi

Tags: python, soapui

I am trying to execute the below script from readyAPi, where as i am getting error

Script which i am executing

`def task = ["/Users/test001/Desktop/Dags ver/phyton_script_validation.py"]
def executeTask = task.execute()
executeTask.waitForOrKill(1000)
//println (executeTask.text)`

Error i am getting

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/test001/Desktop/Dags ver/phyton_script_validation.py": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified error at line: 2
```

Also please let me know whether i have to import any libraries/Jar/utils to run the python script in ReadyAPi?

Thanks

Comment: Error clearly mean file doesnot exists. check path of the file and it is recommended not to have spaces in file path. instead use underscore(_)

Comment: Check that if the same command works in your commandline.